# NumHiddenUnits in LSTM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When we create an `LSTM` layer in matlab then we specify `numHiddenUnits` as `layer = lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)`. I have two questions about it.

(1) : What is mean by `numHiddenUnits`?

Does it represent the number of `LSTM` cells? If yes then are these cells connected serially or parallel(having no interaction between them).

Unfortunately, there is no way to visualize the (RNN)network. I understand how one LSTM cell works but i have no idea how the following architecture looks like.

My networks is made up of these layers.

```
layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(numFeatures)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)
    fullyConnectedLayer(numResponses)
    regressionLayer];
```

(2): How does this architecture looks like?

My approach: I tried to sketch it and i think it should look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `numHiddenUnits` is the dimensionality of the LSTM hidden state. For instance, if you set `numHiddenUnits = 5` , then the LSTM output is a 5-dimensional vector. So, it doesn't represent the number of LSTM cells.
2. [This tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/sequence-to-sequence-regression-using-deep-learning.html) would help you to understand your model better. Your model works like this: At each time LSTM receives an input and processes it BUT doesn't output until the last time step. At the last time-step, your LSTM outputs a vector and sends it to the fully-connected layer and gives you the regression value. Your sketch would be ok if only your last LSTM cell sends an output to the fully-connected layer, not all of them.

Hope this helps

Comment: I figured it out by using analyzenetwork. However, your explanation is correct and can be helpful for someone else.